# What User-Agent should I use when crawling sites using own program

Tags: http, http-headers, user-agent

I made crawler with node.js. I want to crawl some sites on an hourly basis.

I tried to find out what user-agent I should use, but I only got results like google bot and bing bot. I don't know if I can use these user-agents.

Could you tell me which user-agent should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you made your own crawler, you can come up with your own name. There's no rules around what the UserAgent may be, but many use a format like `name/version`, like:

```
myAwesomeCrawler/1.0
```

You could also include a url so website owners can find more information about your bot if they see it in your logs:

```
myAwesomeCrawler/1.0 (http://example.org)
```

But ultimately it's up to you.

This is of course all dependent on you doing something that's not illegal or violates the terms of service of the website you're crawling.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you want to achieve. If you want to imitate a legit browser, simply take the useragent of a common browser like Chrome or Firefox. If you want to tell the site that you're a crawler, simply use something you define (e.g. xyzCrawler).